# Table-valued functions mixing up columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm switching some sql logic handled in application via multiple back and forth database calls into sql stored procedures and functions so one call can do the work of what was previously many.

Much of this logic requires joining between different subsets of data and as a result I've built those into functions to allow easy joining. This is going great however every now and then the functions seem to go a little crazy and start mixing up my columns. I think this is happening as a result of modifications I'm making further up the stack as I develop the application further however I'm not sure.

Below is the column specification relating to language locking.

[image: Column spec]

And below is the function which is suffering from mixed up columns. It makes a call to another function with significantly more complicated logic so i won't bother posting that, but rather the results of a direct call to that functions.

[image: Function spec]

And finally the results of a query to both the problematic function, and the inner function that uses as its data source. The source function is returning the data correctly, yet a select * from the other function causes the data to get completely mixed up, this obviously causes the logic further down the line to fail entirely.

[image: Function results]

Any ideas what the hell is going on? Is it as I suspected the result of other changes? If so, is there a way to cascade?

Thanks

**Edit** Further examination revealed that the problematic function is missing two columns to the left, despite the select *

Comment: Name the columns you are selecting in your query. If you name them they will (a) always return in the order you've defined and (b) break cleanly when the underlying data source changes (i.e., your missing column/renamed column will be immediately obvious).

Comment: It's not the order of the columns, it's the data in them. A bit field has a VARCHAR in it. Look at IsLanguageLocked between the two result sets

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need to use [sp_refreshsqlmodule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx) to fix the metadata. Most likely you've dropped and recreated the underlying function without doing the same to the calling one.

Apart from that, a couple of other things to bear in mind are:

- Never use `SELECT *`; always name the columns
- Consider using [WITH SCHEMABINDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) to avoid unnoticed changes to the underlying function

Comment: Excellent answer, that seems to be it. Thanks!